Is it possible to concurrently read and write to SQL from sibling Go threads?
I'm essentially doing an ETL on a large SQL table. I need to pull rows, perform a calculation, then write them back to the same server but a different table. What I'm seeing is workChannel fill up then everything stops. If I take out the SQL insert statement it runs through all rows. I thought that by opening a SQL connection within the reader thread and another in the main thread they wouldn't block each other, but that seems to not be the case.

func startReader() chan RawData {  
    readerChannel := make(chan RawData, 10)  
    defer close(readerChannel)  

    go func() {
      // Open a DB connection and select large row count.
      for query.Next() {
          // prep rawDataStruct
          readerChannel <- rawDataStruct
      }
    }()
    return readerChannel 
}


func startWorkers(readerChannel chan RawData, workers int) chan CalcData {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(workers)
    workerChannel := make(chan CalcData, 10)

    for ; workers > 0; workers-- {
      go func() {
        rawData, isOpen := <- readerChannel
        if !isOpen {
          return
        }
        workerChannel <- doCalculations(rawData)
      }()
    }()

    go func() {
      wg.Wait()
      close(workerChannel)
    }()
    return workerChannel
 }

 func main() {
  readerChannel := startReader()
  workerChannel := startWorkers(readerChannel, 2)
    
    // open new sql connection
    for {
      calcData, isOpen := workerChannel
      if !isOpen {
        break
      }
      // issue insert query against database connection.
    }
}



There's no SQL in your code. It might be important.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247625/concurrent-mysql-writing-with-gorm-leads-to-an-error/75247928#75247928

@Schwern It is not. A 'select * from table' and an 'insert into otherTable values(...)'

After fixing the syntax errors and replacing the SQL calls with some simple integers...

You fail to call wg.Done() so wg.Wait() will never return.
Your workers don't loop, so they only ever process one item each then exit.
You close the readerChannel too soon.

Your workers should loop like so. Note the use of a for loop which automatically checks for a closed channel.
    for ; workers > 0; workers-- {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for rawData := range readerChannel {
                // process rawData
                workerChannel <- rawData
            }
        }()
    }

Your main function can similarly be simplified.
func main() {
    readerChannel := startReader()
    workerChannel := startWorkers(readerChannel, 2)

    for calcData := range workerChannel {
        fmt.Println(calcData)
    }
}

Demonstration.

I'm not sure what you mean by closing worker channel with a defer. startWorkers returns immediately, but the workers will finish their last write at different times. But you might be right about simplifying the closures.

Also, I corrected the startWorkers returning readerChannel. Its right in the original code.

@gph If the SQL does not matter, please provide a working example which demonstrates the problem (feed the reader channel integers or something) so we can be sure we're finding real bugs.

You almost certainly do not intend closing the readerChannel upon exit of the startReader function, which is what your code (as shown) currently does:
func startReader() chan RawData {  
    readerChannel := make(chan RawData, 10)
    defer close(readerChannel)  // <- closes when startReader exits

    go func() {
      // Open a DB connection and select large row count.
      for query.Next() {
          // prep rawDataStruct
          readerChannel <- rawDataStruct
      }
    }()
    return readerChannel 
}

The defer close(readerChannel) should be inside the goroutine, closing the channel only once all data has been retrieved from the DB and sent to the channel:
func startReader() chan RawData {  
    readerChannel := make(chan RawData, 10)
    go func() {
      defer close(readerChannel)  // <- close when all data read
    
      // Open a DB connection and select large row count.
      for query.Next() {
          // prep rawDataStruct
          readerChannel <- rawDataStruct
      }
    }()
    return readerChannel 
}

